# AWS Powershell Core Lambda accessing S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am working on building a lambda that requires loading a .pfx file from an S3 bucket.
Following the base tutorial, I was able to create and deploy my lambda. However, when calling any of the S3 powershell commands, the lambda either hangs until it times out or provides the error

[Error] - No credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults.

I have created an execution role that contains AWSLambdaExecute and have verified Allow: s3:GetObject is applied.

It acts like it is trying to utilize the AWS CLI configuration roles, which I would expect the IAM role to handle authentication.

I do not wish to use HTTP calls to download from S3, as these need to not be public buckets.

Can anyone add any insight on how I can use AWS Powershell Cmdlets within a lambda to perform AWS tasks?

My org does not allow for creation of IAM users so generating an access key for this purpose is out of the question.

Comment: How do you call s3 command from powershell if you don't have IAM configured?

Answer (score 0):

You  need to provide an **IAM role to your AWS Lambda function**. This IAM role should `have a policy that enables it to get objects (files) from your S3 bucket`. If you provisioned the lambda functon using point and click via console, you can use the template below to provision the required IAM role:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ExampleStmt",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::AWSDOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If you provisioned the Lambda function using `SAM` templates, you can use the following Yaml to provide your lambda the IAM role:

```yaml
PfxDependentFunction:
  Type: "AWS::Serverless::Function"
  Name: "pfx-dependent-function"
  Properties:
    CodeUri: pfx-dependent-function/
    Handler: app.execute
    Timeout: 30 # Seconds
    Runtime: Python 3.8 # Could be replaced
    MemorySize: 512
    Policies:
      - S3ReadPolicy:
          BucketName: "s3-containing-your-csv"
```

Comment: Allan - I have a role created, and within this role I have the built-in policy of AWSLambdaExecute which grants CloudWatch and S3 access. This role is applied to my lambda function.
I created my lambda using the appropriate powershell commandlets, and deploying via the Publish-AWSPowerShellLambda method.
I have tried the command get-s3object and read-s3object. If I specify a profile to use in the commands, I get the error regarding missing shell credentials. If no role is specified, the command 'hangs' until it times out.

Comment: @DerekBotbyl, is your lambda running inside a VPC? do you have internet gateway? VPC endpoints?

Comment: I have the lambda in a VPC with an internet gateway and a Gateway VPC endpoint

Comment: Clarify- the VPC Gateway Endpoint is for S3

Comment: I have now cleared out all of the configuration I had set up and started from scratch. Created a role to grant access to secrets manager, and lambda execute. Created a test secret.
Deployed two lambdas with that role attached, one python one powershell.
No VPC attached to either.
They both do the same thing; read the value of the key.
The python lambda successfully reads the value, the powershell times out.
I am wondering if the method by which I am deploying the powershell lambda is somehow faulty.